# 는 at the end of a sentence?

Tags: grammar, spoken-korean

I'm watching a video on 부산사투리 (https://youtu.be/jtlodca6UN4) and a couple of people have used 는 at the end of a sentence. Here are the exact phrases:

> 주변에 시선이 좀 느껴지는?

> 산맥이나 큰 강같이 교통과 교류의 장애가 되는. 그런 점들을 기준으로 차이가 따로 발달하게 되는.

I was wondering if this was just a slightly truncated form of -는 것 as a means to add a conversational tone?

Comment: You are right. They just didn't complete those sentences.

Answer (score 1):

"A slightly truncated form of -는 것" is a good take on it. This is not a normal speech. Some people started using this and other truncated sentence endings basically as an amusement. 는 ending has an effect of having the listener in suspension because you'd expect something else to come after it.

Comment: ah i see, thanks so much, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

주변에 시선이 좀 느껴지는?

This sounds like the speaker is not trying to make it too strong. The speaker is feeling others are looking at him or her but not staring. And you can find this way of speech quite often not just in Busan.

산맥이나 큰 강같이 교통과 교류의 장애가 되는. 그런 점들을 기준으로 차이가 따로 발달하게 되는.
This is one of the forms of informal languages, or I cannot say it is even a from. I don't think you find these a lot of times. But you could just understand that they are just not finishing up the sentences.